# stopService() with only one client but onDestroy() is not executed

Tags: android, service

I use local service named `PollerService` with one client (activity in the same app named `PollerClient`),
but when I call

```
 stopService(new Intent(PollerClient.this, PollerService.class)
```

Note that, the code `onDestroy()` has not been executed though the service has only one client that started it by

```
startService(new Intent(PollerClient.this, PollerService.class))
```

and stopped it as above by `stopService()`

Can any one tell me, why `onDestroy()`  has not been executed ?

Comment: Please post your code over here !!

Comment: Return value from `onStartCommand` is matters, bound or not bound service matters, existing thread or receivers matters. We can not guess what you did in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't looked into this in detail, but I suspect that as long as the memory isn't needed for something else, Android may be keeping it around in case you start it again.